# WPF column header click command binding with command parameter MVVM

Tags: wpf, xaml, sorting, datagrid, command

I am trying to handle the sort functionality in WPF DataGrid by myself.
I need to be able to bind a command when column header is clicked and send the bound property name as command parameter to the command.

Here is what I have currently :

**XAML:**

```
       <DataGrid Grid.Row="2" Margin="{StaticResource ControlStartPosition}"
        RowStyle="{StaticResource SelectedRowNoBackgroundColor}"
        CellStyle="{StaticResource SelectedCellNoBackgroundColor}"
        Style="{StaticResource AlternatingRowBackgroundGridStyle}"
        x:Name="MechanicsGrid"  
        ItemsSource="{Binding Mechanics}"
        IsReadOnly="True"
        GridLinesVisibility="All"
        SelectionUnit="FullRow"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroDataGridColumnHeader}">
                <Setter Property="Controls:ControlsHelper.ContentCharacterCasing" Value="Normal"/>
                <Setter Property="Command"  Value="{Binding DataContext.GridSortCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" />
                <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding Path=Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
            </Style>

        </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn  Width="*"  Header="{x:Static p:MechanicsView.GridMechanicNameColumn}" Binding="{Binding Name}" />

                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.DeleteMechanicCommand,RelativeSource= {RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" 
                                CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Id}" Width="27" Height="27" Margin="10 -5 10 -5" Style="{DynamicResource MetroCircleButtonStyle}">
                                <Rectangle Width="11" Height="11" Fill="{Binding Path=Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}">
                                    <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                                        <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill" Visual="{DynamicResource appbar_close}" />
                                    </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                                </Rectangle>
                            </Button>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

**ViewModels:**

```
    private ObservableCollection<MechanicModel> mechanics;
    public ObservableCollection<MechanicModel> Mechanics
    {
        get
        {
            return mechanics;
        }
        set
        {
            Set(() => Mechanics, ref mechanics, value);
        }
    }
```

Grid is bound to this property, in mechanic model i just have two properties:

```
    private int id;
    public int Id
    {
        get
        {
            return id;
        }
        set
        {
            Set(() => Id, ref id, value);
        }
    }

    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return  name;
        }
        set
        {
            Set(() => Name, ref  name, value);
            ValidateProperty(nameof(Name), value);
        }
    }
```

**Command:**

The command bound to the column header is:

```
    private RelayCommand<object> gridSortCommand;
    public RelayCommand<object> GridSortCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return gridSortCommand
                ?? (gridSortCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(
                p =>
                {

                },
                p => true));
        }
    }
```

So for p => I currently get the Title of the column, what i want to get is the property name in this case at least "Name" as string so i can construct my sorting logic in the view model.Unfortenatly i can not bind  it as command parameter.

Comment: Do you need this to be in your `ViewModel`? This is sort of `View` specific functionality which could be done in the code behind. And here is a [link to msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407126(v=vs.100).aspx#Anchor_2) on how to do the sort.

Comment: I see your point, thanks for the link.
I also have paging and my data loading repository is in the view model and i thought providing the data to the view is  ViewModel's responsibility.

Comment: Ah I see, you didn't mention paging in the post. This will complicate things a little, as you will have to do it in the `VM` to provide valid pages. As for the `CommandParameter` use `MultiBinding` instead, that will give you facility to pass multiple parameters, the parameter then becomes `object[]`. HTH. If you need any more help with the MultiBinding I'll whip up an answer for you.

Comment: Well in my case it will be helpful if you could provide me an example for MultiBinding.
Ideally I would like to pass columns bound property name and the order of sorting but it seems that i won't be abel to manage this from XAML code.

Comment: Have you had any luck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass parameters in your command all you need to do is to use `MultiBinding`
This then can be used as follows:

```
<MultiBinding>
    <Binding Path="Id"/>
    <Binding Path="Name"/>
    <Binding Path="DirectionOfSort"/>
</MultiBinding>
```

However, to do that you will need to change your xaml a little.
So from :

```
<Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding Path=Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
```

you need to change it to:

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
            <Setter Property="CommandParameter">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource multi}">
                        <Binding Path="Id"/>
                        <Binding Path="Name"/>
                        <Binding Path="{x:Static util:Enumeration.EDirection}"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

where your converter is like this:

```
namespace View.Converters
{
    public class MultiValueConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return values.Clone();
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

And in xaml:

```
<converter:MultiValueConverter x:Key="multi"/>
```

Which you reference like so:

```
xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:View.Converters"
```

Where your `Util` is basically an enumeration which is referenced in your xaml like so:

```
xmlns:util="clr-namespace:Utilities;assembly=Utilities"
```